# Android support for multiple devices and screens

Tags: android, screen

I have created the following layouts to support multiple devices and screens:

```
layout-normal
layout-normal-land
layout-sw240dp
layout-sw240dp-land
layout-sw320dp
layout-sw320dp-land
```

and included the following in manifest

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

I have also created a AVD with ICS 4.0.3 
skin WVGA800,LCD density 240..etc

When i run my app on the emulator i have observed that it loads some
resources from layout-sw240dp and some from layout-sw320dp

I confirmed it by changing some text in the XML files of these directories.

My question is for the same device config why should it load resources from different
layout directories?.

I could not find any info regarding this problem in android Multiple screens support documentation.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html. Check the link for Supporting multiple screeens. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFhgmS2Kc7k. Supporting multi versions and avoiding code duplication. Please go through the links.

Comment: sorry. i have already read the screens_support and also seen this video now. This is does not answer my problem